Prettier formatting remove the space after comma in SQL
I have this query:
SELECT
    column1,column2,column3

FROM
    table_stage

Then I set prettier to put the comma before the value but I get this result:
SELECT
    column1
  , column2
  , column3
FROM
    table_stage

Is there a way in prettier to remove the space after the comma?
Expected Output:
SELECT
    column1
  ,column2
  ,column3
FROM
    table_stage

Thanks!

I use this plugn all the time, never mess with the settings, use default as much as possible prettier v1.6.0:
SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
FROM
    table_stage


Unfortunately it's a requirement for other project. If it's not possible then I can't use prettier for formating.
